# Access to python data strucure

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data variable in python and i dont know to access on elements.
Here is the data structure example:

`('deploy_with_config', [{'port': 80, 'name': 'test1', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'test2', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}])`

This data must in a textfile, each line for entry.
For this example:
test1 0.0.0.0 80
test2 0.0.0.0 80

Comment: question is not clear...elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got a tuple (an immutable list) which you can index into. You want the second item in the tuple so you call a[1]. This is a list of dictionaries, each one split by the curly braces {}. To call an item in the dictionary you use the square brackets and call the dictionary key (the word on the left of the ':'). This gives you the corresponding value, "test1" etc.

If you're unclear of exactly how the code works, go through each stage and loop through the items first of the tuple, then through the dictionaries and play around with the calling syntax.

```
a = ('deploy_with_config', [{'port': 80, 'name': 'test1', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'test2', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}])

for some_dict in a[1]:
    print(some_dict["name"], some_dict["address"], some_dict["port"])
```

Comment: Using reserved names like `dict` as variable names is discouraged, because here it shadows the whole [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict) class.

Comment: Didn't notice but you're right

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is a tuple, consisting of a string and a list. The list itself contains dictionaries, each with 3 key-value-pairs.

You can find out this sort of information like this:

```
>>> unknown_data = ('deploy_with_config', [{'port': 80, 'name': 'test1', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'test2', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}])

>>> type(unknown_data)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(unknown_data[0])
<class 'str'>
>>> type(unknown_data[1])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(unknown_data[1][0])
<class 'dict'>
```

To get the output format you suggested, you could do something like:

```
for item in unknown_data[1]:
    print('{0[name]} {0[address]} {0[port]}'.format(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume data is a tuple

```
data = ('deploy_with_config', [{'port': 80, 'name': 'test1', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'test2', 'address': '0.0.0.0'}])

params = data[1]
params = [" ".join([item['name'], item['address'], str(item['port'])]) for item in params]

with open('data.txt') as fw:
    fw.writelines(params)
```